# Could not find agent library for JRebel

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, jrebel

I have added the correct JRebel path to my local.properties file. but then am facing below error

> Could not find agent library C:Userspramod.p2poolpluginsorg.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_2018.1.5.RELEASEjrebellibjrebel64.dll in absolute path, with error: Can't find dependent libraries

here is my configuration:

tomcat.javaoptions=agentpath:"C:\Users\pramod.p2\pool\plugins\org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_2018.1.5.RELEASE\jrebel\lib\jrebel64.dll"

Please do let me know, if am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Use forward slashes (/) instead of backwards one (\) for file path.

Comment: or, escape them via double backslash `\\\`. I recommend that you get yourself a linux VM to develop hybris. the build is usually around 50-100% faster than on windows

Answer (score 0):

> Can't find dependent libraries

Means that the JVM found the JRebel agent, but was unable to link its dependent dll-s.

To figure out what exactly is missing on your system, you can run the http://www.dependencywalker.com tool or similar against jrebel64.dll

Information about Windows version and any other system information would also help figure out why it's incompatible.